# Do 饶舌 and 说唱 mean the same thing in Chinese?

Tags: difference, slang

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E9%A5%B6%E8%88%8C) gives "Rap" for "饶舌" and ["说唱" for "Rap"](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=zh-CN&text=Rap)

Do 饶舌 and 说唱 mean the same thing in Chinese?

Is it about spoken vs. written?

Comment: Not always. 饒舌could also mean talkative, usually implying talking too much. In fact, this is it's traditional meaning.

Comment: There's also 嘻哈 hip-hop, which used to be quite an uncommon word but has been popularized by the TV show 《中国有嘻哈》. Though upon Googling it, looks like they changed the show's name to 《中国新说唱》 recently!

Answer (score 1):

饶舌 and 说唱 do have the same meaning in Chinese when you are talking about music.

Taiwan hiphop singers translate rap to 饶舌.

Mainland ones translate rap to 说唱.

As an example:

- mc_hotdog (from Taiwan) uses 饶舌 to refer to rap in his lyrics.
- kindergarten killer（from the mainland）uses 说唱 to refer to rap in his lyrics.

The relation between 饶舌（Taiwan) and 说唱（Mainland）is just like the one between graduate (U.S.) and postgraduate (U.K.).

But when you are not just talking about music, 饶舌 have a wider definition, just as Raynoceros said.

Comment: Upvoted. It would be nice if you could also add a couple links to the lyrics of mc_hotdog and KK, for completeness

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you ask me the difference between 说唱 and 饶舌 in Chinese, I can not tell the difference.

There are also many Chinese have asked this question online. The answer is that they are almost the same, perhaps 饶舌 will be used more in southern China (Hong Kong and Taiwan).

Answer (score 0):

饶舌, a kind of popular music, (for me) it usually means difficult to understand what the singer sings/speaks, because they sing/speak too FAST to understand or too FAST to follow the lyrics.

說唱 not only for popular music, but a kind of performing arts also, such as 相聲(crosstalk). 相聲是一種說唱藝術(Crosstalk is an art of talking and singing)

饶舌 說唱 usually have the identical meaning in daily life.

Answer (score 0):

`饶舌` purely means nagging, equal meaning to `唠叨`

`说唱` is a new terms for rapping.

`说` means talk while `唱` means sing, so singing while talking there you go.

Comment: 饒舌絕對不是唠叨，饒舌的意思跟饒口差不多，聽過繞口令大概就知道為什麼要叫饒舌歌了。說唱也不是新詞，頂多是被借指到饒舌歌，因為很多饒舌歌聽起來就是說話加唱歌。

Comment: 饶 had the meaning of more. In a world before Rap, 饶舌 originally mean talk a lot, talkative and nagging. Because when you have too many tongue, it just sounds annoying.(唠叨)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that 饶舌  is a *type* of 说唱.

饶舌 is more like something hard to speak like *tongue twisters*.  The lyrics or words are twisted(绕在一起) and hard to pronounce and singers are skillful.

说唱 is more general for any types of speaking forms in singing.  No matter the lyrics or words are hard to pronounce or not.

If you can read Chinese, this addresses it well:

> 说唱就是纯说没什么语言上的技巧，饶舌就是玩技巧，玩文字游戏。
> 说唱指曲艺表演，RAP既为说唱乐。说唱乐在世界各地广泛传播。
> 饶舌，有唠叨、多嘴之意。饶舌歌是黑人英语发展而来，黑人英语融合了黑人民族原有英文的普遍性，经由黑人饶舌歌手快歌快语的说唱，饶舌歌曲不但用字简化许多，在文法使用上，也有所转变，自成一格，更与白人英语形成极大分野。